# Java 2d array TicTacToe NumberFormat error

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, logic

My method `entreeIncorrecte` is there to check for user input. If the value for `ligne` and `colonne` are anything other than "0", "1", "2" or "3", I want to print out that the user was incorrect and restart the loop for `entreeIncorrecte`. If I enter "e" and "3" for the row and column, the compiler gives me:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "e"   at
>   java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)    at
>   td.Main.verifierEntree(Main.java:200)     at
>   td.Main.jouerUnePartie(Main.java:152)     at
>   td.Main.plusieursParties(Main.java:103)   at td.Main.main(Main.java:32)

Is there anything to do about that?

N.B.: The code has to be written in French for my variables, methods, etc. by convention because of where I live, so sorry in advance for any confusion. Here is my code:

```
package td;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


// Initialisation des variables
public static String ligne, colonne;
public static Scanner scan;
public static char[][] tableau = new char[4][4];
public static char tourJoueur = 'O';
public static Random rand;
public static int scoreJ1;
public static int scoreJ2;
public static String nomJoueur1;
public static String nomJoueur2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            tableau[i][j] = ' ';
            // Introduction avant les jeux
            menuIntroduction();

            // Toutes les parties
            plusieursParties();

            // Message final
            menuFin();
        }
    }
}

private static void menuIntroduction() {
    printIntro();

    scoreJ1 = 0;
    scoreJ2 = 0;

    // Initialisation du Scanner
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Recuperation des noms des joueurs
    System.out.println("Joueur 1 rentrez votre nom");
    nomJoueur1 = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Joueur 2 rentrez votre nom");
    nomJoueur2 = scan.nextLine();

    // Choix du premier joueur au hasard
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (rand.nextInt() % 2 == 0) {
        tourJoueur = 'O';
    } else {
        tourJoueur = 'X';

    }
}

private static void printIntro() {
    System.out.println("BIENVENU AU TIC TAC TOE!\n");
    System.out.println("Chaque joueur se fera assigner 'X' ou 'O'\n");
    System.out.println("Chaque joueur selectionnera une case dans le Tic Tac Toe.\n");
    System.out.println(
            "Il faudra selectionner une ligne (de 0-3) et peser sur ENTER. Il faudra ensuite selectionner une colonne et peser sur ENTER\n");
    System.out.println("Chaque joueur se fera assigner 'X' ou 'O', débutant par le joueur 1\n");
    System.out.println(
            "Pour gagner, il faudra compléter une ligne du tableau avec 'X' ou 'O', soit verticalement, soit horizontalement, soit diagonalement\n");
    System.out.println("Si le tableau est plein et qu'aucun joueur n'a fait de ligne, la partie sera nulle\n");
    System.out.println("Chaque partie gagnée donnera un point au joueur vainqueur\n");
    System.out.println("Bonne partie!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("========================================================\n\n\n");

}

private static void menuFin() {
    System.out.println("=========================FIN DU JEU=========================\n\n\n");
    System.out.println("merci à " + nomJoueur1 + " et " + nomJoueur2 + " d'avoir joué ! ");

    // message de fin different selon le joueur gagnant ou s'il y a égalité
    if (scoreJ1 > scoreJ2) {
        System.out.println(nomJoueur1 + " l'emporte à " + scoreJ1 + " contre " + scoreJ2);
    } else if (scoreJ2 > scoreJ1) {
        System.out.println(nomJoueur2 + " l'emporte à " + scoreJ2 + " contre " + scoreJ1);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Égalité! " + scoreJ1 + " point(s) au total!");
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\nÀ bientôt!");

}

private static void plusieursParties() {
    do {

        jouerUnePartie(tourJoueur);

    } while (onContinue());
}

private static boolean onContinue() {
    boolean inputContinue = false;
    boolean entreeIncorrecte = true;

    // tant que l'utilisateur ecrit n'importe quoi on lui redemande de faire un
    // choix
    do {
        System.out.println("les scores sont : ");
        System.out.println(nomJoueur1 + " : " + scoreJ1 + "  |||  " + nomJoueur2 + " : " + scoreJ2);
        System.out.println("voulez - vous continuer ? [Oui/Non]");

        String reponseUser = scan.nextLine();

        // cas un et deux reponse valide et transmise, cas trois le user dit n'importe
        // quoi
        if (reponseUser.equals("Oui")) {
            inputContinue = true;
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
        } else if (reponseUser.equals("Non")) {
            inputContinue = false;
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Erreur, entrez 'Oui' ou 'Non'");
            entreeIncorrecte = true;
        }

    } while (entreeIncorrecte);

    // on renvoie la reponse de l'utilisateur lorsqu'elle est valide
    return inputContinue;
}

private static void jouerUnePartie(char tourJoueur1) {
    System.out.println("C'est au tour de " + nomJoueur1 + "!" + "Tu joues " + tourJoueur + "!\n");
    System.out.println("Entre une ligne et pèse sur ENTER");
    System.out.println("Entre une colonne et pèse sur ENTER");

    // Verifie si l'utilisateur utilise un chiffre et non quelque chose d'autre pour
    // ligne et pour colonne
    boolean jouant = true;
    do {
        afficherTableau();
        verifierEntree();

    } while (jouant);
    {
        int colonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);
        int ligne2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne);

        tableau[ligne2][colonne2] = tourJoueur;
        if (victoire(scoreJ1, scoreJ1) && !tableauPlein()) {
            System.out.println("Felicitations! Le joueur " + tourJoueur + " gagne!");
            jouant = false;
        }


        if (!victoire(ligne2, colonne2) && tableauPlein()) {
            System.out.println("Partie nulle!");
            jouant = false;
        } else {
            jouant = true;
        }
        if (tourJoueur == 'O') {
            tourJoueur = 'X';
        } else {
            tourJoueur = 'O';
        }

    }
}

private static void verifierEntree() {

    boolean entreeIncorrecte = true;
    while (entreeIncorrecte) {

        ligne = scan.nextLine();
        colonne = scan.nextLine();

        if (ligne.contentEquals("0")) {
        }
        if (ligne.equals("0") || ligne.equals("1") || ligne.equals("2") || ligne.equals("3")) {
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
        } else if (colonne.equals("0") || colonne.equals("1") || colonne.equals("2") || colonne.equals("3")) {
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Mauvaise entree! Recommence! ");
            entreeIncorrecte = true;
        }
        if (!entreeIncorrecte) {
            // Comment colonne2 et ligne2 ne sont pas utilisés?
            int colonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);
            int ligne2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne);
        } else {

        }
    }
}

private static boolean victoire(int ligne2, int colonne2) {

    // Verifie horizontalement la victoire

    if (tableau[0][colonne2] == tableau[1][colonne2] && tableau[0][colonne2] == tableau[2][colonne2]
            && tableau[0][colonne2] == tableau[3][colonne2])
        return true;

    // Verifie verticalement la victoire

    if (tableau[ligne2][0] == tableau[ligne2][1] && tableau[ligne2][0] == tableau[ligne2][2]
            && tableau[ligne2][0] == tableau[ligne2][3])
        return true;

    // Verifie diagonalement vers la droite la victoire

    if (tableau[0][0] == tableau[1][1] && tableau[0][0] == tableau[2][2] && tableau[0][0] == tableau[3][3]
            && tableau[1][1] != ' ')
        return true;

    // Verifie diagonalement vers la gauche la victoire

    if (tableau[0][3] == tableau[1][2] && tableau[0][3] == tableau[2][1] && tableau[0][3] == tableau[3][0]
            && tableau[1][2] != ' ')
        return true;
    if (tableauPlein())
        return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean tableauPlein() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (tableau[i][j] == ' ') {
                // Un tour peut etre fait, tableau non vide
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;

}

private static void afficherTableau() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print(" |");
            }
            System.out.print(tableau[i][j] + " |");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: A) that is a runtime exception, not a compile time error message. Details matter! B) your code expects the user to enter numbers, you enter a non number, an exception is thrown, clearly stating that the string "e" is not a number. So what is your question? Nothing in here is surprising, and that exception and that method is extensively documented.

Comment: Check your logic in `verifierEntree`.  Once you have decided that `ligne` is not incorrect, you don't check `colonne`.  I think you might find the logic easier to work out if you formulate it in terms of the input either being "correct" nor "not correct", rather than "incorrect" and "not incorrect".

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the correction! You see, I started Java 2 weeks ago for an 
 obligatory intro class, with me being a BBA student, so all this is new to me. My question is : How can I change my code so that if the user enters anything other than a number (From 0 to 3) as a String, it prints out that the user entered a wrong input and restarts the loops for `entreeIncorrecte`? Sorry if any of this is redundant.

Comment: Can you confirm that the exception you get (which is on line 200) is `int colonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);`? It doesn't match up for me in the editor I'm using, so I want to make sure I'm at the right line.

Comment: additional hint:  redefining the variables inside the if block makes no sense. (the "int  colonne2" should be only colonne2 without the "int" prepended)

Comment: I understand. But this place has its rules and policies, too. There are no shortcuts here. Reasonable questions need to follow [mcve], and instead of pasting all your code, you could have created a small example using English for your variables. Beyond that, you are almost there: you simply could catch that exception and use that information to understand "the user did not provide a number". There are many places out there that explain all such details. You should not expect that we write down this one more time again, just for you.

Comment: @Water Yes, on line 200 is the warning for `int colonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);` I'm using Eclipse if that's any help.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for linking that help section. It'll definitely come in handy so I don't ask another question like this. We have not been shown how to catch exceptions yet, however.

Comment: That is my point: this community isn't a replacement for learning the basics. If you aren't supposed to use try/catch, the next best thing is to retrieve a string from the scanner and then you have to write a method that checks if that string only contains digits and can be safely parsed as number. But that is of course reinventing the wheel, because such validation is exactly what that parse method does!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for being honest with me. My class/teacher doesn't have us learn most of these programming basics. It has us learn the barest of beginner's basics. For more experienced programmers, it can be irritating when I ask about well documented topics such as these. I'll be more considerate to the community moving forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

French is fine but unfortunately my french knowledge is very limited. So I am just guessing "entreeIncorrecte" signals a wrong userinput. Otherwise it might at least be a syntactical help:

```
int colonne2 = 0;
int ligne2 = 0;
try{
   colonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);
   ligne2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne);
} catch (NumberFormatException ignored){
    entreeIncorrecte = true;
}
```

This would set the variables to 0 if you entered a letter like "e" and set the variable entreeIncorrecte to true.

And this *might* be a replacment of your whole method(milage my vary):

```
private static void verifierEntree() {
    int intcolonne2 = 0;
    int intligne2 = 0; 
    boolean entreeIncorrecte = true;
    while (entreeIncorrecte) {

        ligne = scan.nextLine();
        colonne = scan.nextLine();

        if (ligne.contentEquals("0")) {
        }
        if (ligne.equals("0") || ligne.equals("1") || ligne.equals("2") || ligne.equals("3")) {
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
        } else if (colonne.equals("0") || colonne.equals("1") || colonne.equals("2") || colonne.equals("3")) {
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Mauvaise entree! Recommence! ");
            entreeIncorrecte = true;
        }
        if (!entreeIncorrecte) {
        // Comment colonne2 et ligne2 ne sont pas utilisés?
            //int colonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);
            //int ligne2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne);
            try{
                intcolonne2 = Integer.parseInt(colonne);
                intligne2 = Integer.parseInt(ligne);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored){
                intcolonne2 = 0;
                intligne2 = 0; 
                entreeIncorrecte = true;
            }
        } //else {

        if(entreeIncorrecte){

        }
     }
 }
```

Or something like this:

```
private static void verifierEntree() {
    int intcolone;
    int intligne;
    boolean entreeIncorrecte = true;
    while (entreeIncorrecte) {

        ligne = scan.nextLine();
        colonne = scan.nextLine();
        switch(ligne){
        case "0": 
        case "1":
        case "2":
        case "3":
            entreeIncorrecte = false;
            intligne = ligne.charAt(0)-'0';
            break;
        default: entreeIncorrecte = true;
        } 

        switch(colonne){
         case "0":
         case "1":
         case "2":
         case "3":
            intcolone = colonne.charAt(0)-'0';
            break;
         default: entreeIncorrecte = true;

         } 
         if(entreeIncorrecte) {
            System.out.println("Mauvaise entree! Recommence!");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You are definitely correct on your guess! I'm checking to signal a wrong user input. I'm not sure where to put the code you wrote or how setting the variables to 0 if a letter was added is useful. Would you care to explain?

Comment: I added another variant that is more parser like.

Comment: implemented your second method and it works great! Only issue is the compiler warns "The value of the local variable intcolone is not used" and "The value of the local variable intligne is not used".

Comment: yes, and the compiler is right: I don't know what you do with your integer values that were the input. you want to do something meaningfull with them.

Comment: The integer values are supposed to serve as coordinate inputs for my `char [ ] [ ] tableau`, which is my gameboard.

Comment: tableau[intligne][intcolone] = 'X'; or something. and you might want to use fields instead or return them somehow if used outside the method.